# play fullscreen video on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I was browsing on squarespace's website and saw that they have a button in the bottom right that plays a fullscreen video after it's clicked. When I used bigvideo.js, the video was blurry, but the one Squarespace uses isn't blurry and it also has it's own player. Does someone know how I could achieve this? I'm mainly wondering about how to make my own player and play a video without linking to another html page.

EDIT: It seems they've put videos as the backgrounds. How could they do that?

LINK: http://www.squarespace.com/

Screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/ilptcpvcx/

Comment: Is your video blurry because the dimensions of your video are less than your full-screen resolution?

Comment: I think so. But what I was really wondering was how they could play it without linking to another html page and how they could make their own player

Comment: Making your own player is complicated, but you could just use something like Flowplayer ( http://flowplayer.org/ ) or just good old HTML5 ( http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp ).

Comment: Oh wow, those are actually pretty good alternatives. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML 5 player has full screen built in.

Alternatively you could look at flowplayer or sublime video.

As for the blurry video are you sure its not just your video quality?

Comment: Furthermore there are tons of tutorials online to customize the look of your HTML5 player using CSS